# On the classification of finite dimensional $\mathbb{k}[X]$-modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $(V,T)$ with $T \in End_{\mathbb{k}}V$ be an $n$-dimensional $\mathbb{k}[X]$-module. If the minimal polynomial $m_T$ has an irreducible factorization $f_1 \cdots f_r$, can we say that:

$$
V \simeq  \bigoplus_{i = 1}^r\frac{\mathbb{k}[X]}{(f_i)} \simeq \frac{(\mathbb{k}[X])^r}{(m_T)}
$$

and if so, can we construct an explicit isomorphism?

I know that since $\operatorname{Ann}_{\mathbb{k}[X]}V = (m_T)$ we have that

$$
V \simeq \bigoplus_{i = 1}^rV[f_i] \simeq \bigoplus_{i = 1}^r\bigoplus_{j = 1}^{n_i}\frac{\mathbb{k}[X]}{(f_i^{s_{ij}})} 
$$

with each $V[f_i]$ the $f_i$-torsion of $V$.

Comment: Two $k[x]$-modules $(V,T),(V',T')$ are isomorphic if and only if there is a vector-space isomorphism $S\colon V\to V'$ such that $T'S=ST$. Choosing bases this means that $T$ and $T'$ are similar matrices. Note that $m_T$ does not determine the conjugacy class of $T$, so it can't determine the isomorphism class of $(V,T)$.

Comment: @Christoph got it. Thanks! It was too good to be true, I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general form is rather
$$\bigoplus_{i=1}^r\bigoplus_{j=1}^{a_i}
\left(\frac{k[X]}{(f_i^{j})}\right)^{n_{i,j}}$$
where $m_T=f_1^{a_1}\cdots f_r^{a_r}$ with
the $f_i$ distinct monic irreducibles. Here the $n_{i,j}$ are
non-negative integers, and $n_{i,a_i}>0$ in order to ensure that
$m_T$ really is the minimum polynomial of $T$.

Comment: Do we have some control over the coefficients $n_{i,j}$? Also, why can we take each $f_i$ monic? I'm not seeing the difference between this decomposition and the one I mentioned at the end of my post other than the factors being monic, since I'm taking into account repeated copies of the same $f_i^j$ as well. Would you mind to clear that up?

Comment: @GuidoA. You basically asserted that **all** the $n_{i,j}=1$. That's not necessarily the case. Monic is a cheap way of ensuring the $f_i$ are non-associates.

Comment: I'm not seeing how I claimed that all $n_{i,j} = 1$ in the *last* part of my post. What it's now clear to me is that the first decomposition that I claimed is false. However, for the latter, I was (I think) re-writing the structure theorem. As for the requirement of the polynomials being monic, we can drop it assuming $f_i \not \sim f_j$ if $i \neq j$, right?So that we don't need $\mathbb{k}$ to be algebraically closed.